# Doubt on the women production in "classical music"

Tags: classical-music, composers

> Just to be very clear about my question. When I wrote the question I was thinking in:
>
> 1. I heard that John Williams was inspired by Gustav Holst's "The Planets"
> 2. I wanted to find similar pieces to apply the same reasoning of Jonh Williams (to be inspired).
> 3. But, I didn't want to be inspired just by music (art in general) produced by men.
> 4. I wanted to hear pieces (here "classical music") composed by women in the context of astronomy. Because, I'm developing a story with a female character, and I want to construct a story that carries references (dialoge, ambient, soundtrack and so on...) on art produced by women.
> 5. Then I wrote this question.

This question is about recommendations merged with some music history.

Gustav Holst produced the master piece called "The Planets". In sci-fi this piece inspired many movietracks like star wars and so on.

But everytime we have a man behind great inspirations, a male composer. I really would like to know female composers that produced master pieces like "The Planets". Where are them?

**My question is: "The Planets" is something that have the subject of astronomy as a fundamental context. Do you know any female composer that produced master pieces with the same context?**

Comment: Some academic folks have written about attitudes embedded in how people talk about music, i.e. the discourse. Fred E Maus from the University of Virginia has something about it https://www.gmth.de/zeitschrift/artikel/1035.aspx   https://www.academia.edu/10617824/Masculine_Discourse_in_Music_Theory Seems like an interesting subject, but also a potentially touchy one. ;)

Comment: Dare we even use the term *masterpiece* without offending *someone*..? Stuff P.C.

Comment: @ojs - to me, it's the equivalent of asking if there are any serious left-handed composers. Sure, someone could probably list them, but what benefit would the question serve? In short, once you unwrap the woke connotations, it's merely 'trivia'. It's neither music practise nor theory, it's a list question, unsuited to the SE format. i vtc as 'opinion-based' for lack of any more appropriate flag.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin, this is a list question that is not about music practice or theory.  Maybe this would be a better fit on Music Fans, but even then it's still a list question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a better fit for MusicFans. I also suggest reframing the question, because it's somewhat unclear: is the question whether women composed music based on "grand" subjects like the cosmos, or is the question looking for women composers whose works are considered masterpieces, regardless the subject matter. And, of course, it needs to be written in a way that allows for specific answers rather than a list of names.

Comment: @Tetsujin isn't idle curiosity good enough reason to ask? Also, if you haven't been aware, during the period when "classical music masterpieces" were composed there was a certain gender imbalance. Reading instead of writing for a while might help with that. I agree that left-handedness wasn't exactly popular either but questions about left-handed musicians haven't been closed as eagerly.

Comment: When gender inequality is mentioned or suggested one needs to be careful how the question is asked, or the outcome might be harmful. As it is I see multiple issues with the question. It ask for an opinion. It's vaguely stated. It doesn't show much research. It doesn't ask about historical context, which in this case might be critical to understand the facts.

Comment: When Holst was making music and when it was possible for new classical "masterpieces" to arise, the world was different and it wasn't possible for women to become classical composers. Now it could be possible for women, but the era of masterpieces is gone already. Why not ask for _black_ female classical composers who've made masterpieces about astronomy. Preferably _from Africa_, of course.

Comment: @Aaron et al, if you read what Fred E. Maus writes about the discourse around music, and especially classical music, it could be argued based on facts that _music theory_ has sexist ideas baked in its structures. (see Masculine Discourse in Music Theory) If I understood correctly, this question is asking "there are no classical masterpieces composed by women born in the 1800s, are there?" ... well, it shouldn't be a matter of opinion to see that there _cannot_ be. It was not possible during the era of classical "masterpieces" for women to become composers.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Although I didn't say it directly, your comment reflects the direction of my thinking. An improved version of the OP would allow for answers that point out the role of male-centered discourse and attitudes regarding women's participation in music.

Comment: Q "Why didn't women in the U.S. vote much before 1920?" ... suggesting that they were not interested in the political process and/or governance? :)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, because I was able to write an answer that feels fairly fact-based and logical. In the answer I'm also trying to say that the kind of music that Hollywood accepts, is kind of old-fashioned, if we compare it to what new classical music is like today. Classical music evolves, it's not what it used to be 100-150 years ago. Which might not be obvious really. I've been to some concerts of new music, it's not Hollywood stuff! ;) Certainly not what you hear in George Lucas films at least.

Comment: I see the edit you just made, and it clarifies your question immensely. Thanks. The kind of question you're asking is off topic, but it would be a great topic for the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).

Comment: Ok, it's not a man/woman thing, you just want old music. If you aren't inspired by Saariaho, then you're not interested in the kind of classical music that's composed today, during the time when women ARE able to be classical composers. Back in the day when Holst was hip and hot, women had to take care of the family and couldn't be composers. Today, only film composers write music that sounds like what classical music was 100 years ago. In concert halls, "film music" and "game music" are excuses for playing the old-fashioned things that normal people like to hear. This is my observation.

Comment: Isn’t this clearly an identification question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what is a masterpiece, but at least Kaija Saariaho's *Orion*, *Io* and *Asteroid 4179: Toutatis* would be in the "classical", "female composer" and "space" department of things. (There may be more, this is what I found)

## "Orion" by Saariaho

https://saariaho.org/works/orion/

> Orion begins its musical journey in a kind of amorphous ‘interstellar
> space’.

## "Io" by Saariaho

https://saariaho.org/works/io/

> the name comes from the third largest of Jupiter’s 14 moons.

Mind you, that's for *orchestra, tape and live electronics*.

## "Asteroid 4179: Toutatis" by Saariaho

https://saariaho.org/works/asteroid-4179-toutatis/

> All these peculiarities, and the fact that Toutatis already has had
> many collisions with other heavenly objects, inspired me to write this
> small work to complete the project that Simon Rattle and the Berlin
> Philharmonic Orchestra created around The Planets of Holst.

Can't get much more astronomical than that!

---

Now to the "masterpiece" question, i.e. why are no female composers listed as a source of inspiration for the composer of the Star Wars music.

https://www.yourclassical.org/story/2015/10/20/star-wars-john-williams-influences

Let's see who are listed

- [Tchaikovsky, born 1840](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyotr_Ilyich_Tchaikovsky)
- [Holst, born 1874](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Holst)
- [Korngold, born 1897](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Wolfgang_Korngold)
- [Stravinsky, born 1882](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Stravinsky)
- [Orff, born 1895](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Orff)
- [Elgar, born 1857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Elgar)

Why are no women listed? In the times when the listed gentlemen roamed the world, it wasn't possible for women to do such a thing as compose masterpieces of Western classical music.

It's not about women, it's about the world. The world in general, and the world of classical music, both of which have changed. The world in general does now allow women to be classical composers - but the classical music of today, and what is "modern", might not fit what Hollywood wants for its movie-selling purposes. But who knows, maybe in the next 100 years, the now-current classical music will be suitable for the then-current entertainment industry.

---

As further proof and evidence, I asked my wife what she thinks, why were there no female classical composers as influences for movie composers. She said two things:

- It's because WOMEN HAD TO TAKE CARE OF THE FAMILY.
- Even if they had a woman, such as their wife, as an influence and inspiration, they won't admit it.

So there!

Comment: [Not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_of_Bingen) [all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Strozzi) [women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Italian_women_classical_composers) had to take care of families, or were unable to compose as a result… (Of course, many clearly _were_ unable, and we are all poorer because of that.)

Comment: @gidds  I don't think I'm making a gross oversimplification by claiming that being a composer was not really a generally accepted viable career path for women born in the 1800s. I'm not sure if it is even today.

Comment: Oh, agreed. I just wanted to point out that there were notable exceptions. (Of course, you might very well say that _all_ composers are exceptional, in a way! But the female ones are exceptional in _another_ way too :-)

Comment: Maybe you and your spouse would enjoy learning about the life and music of Clara Schumann (for starters).

Answer (score 3):

"Masterpiece" is a rather subjective term. The late jazz saxophonist and composer, [Barbara Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Thompson_(musician)), composed and produced the Album *[Heavenly Bodies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AncZYrsH1H0&list=OLAK5uy_kdzkrZ0GJJvOz6-9g2g5VtMOYQfZfjAvU&ab_channel=BarbaraThompson-Topic)* which is astronomically based.